# How to get console.timeEnd value and put to array?

Tags: firefox-addon

I use `console.timeEnd` and `console.time` for some timing. I would like to push these times into an array and do some stats on them. However neither .time nor .timeEnd is returning a value. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
var blah = console.time('path');
var path = FileUtils.getFile('DefProfRt', []).path;
var blah2 = console.timeEnd('path');
console.log('blah', blah);
console.log('blah2', blah2);
```

I know i can set a time before and after with `new Date.getTime()` but i was hoping to use the console feature i like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ConsoleAPIStorage service. The `getEvents` method returns all console events (you can also pass the inner window id, when available, as an argument)

```js
let consoleAPIStorage = Cc["@mozilla.org/consoleAPI-storage;1"].getService(Ci.nsIConsoleAPIStorage);

var events = consoleAPIStorage.getEvents().filter(function(ev){
  return ev.timer !== null && // get only time and timeEnd events
         ev.filename == "filename.js"; // get specific js scope
});
```

I guess you are interested in `events[0].level` (`time` or `timeEnd`), `events[0].timer.name` (the timer name), `events[0].timeStamp`, `events[0].timer.started` (if this is a `time` event) and `events[0].timer.duration` (if `timeEnd` event).